# Setting parameters efficiently in S4 objects

Tags: r, r-s4

I am writing a simulation model in R to track the behavior of a set of interacting agents.  For my own sanity, I give each agent its own S4 object, in which I store its trajectory and other parameters.  Currently, I pass an object to a function, do some operations, and pass the object back.  For example,

```
#Create a new class and a sample object
setClass("example", slots = list(N="numeric"), prototype = list(N=0))    
agentA<-new("example") 

#Define a function to change the value in the N slot
add_one<-function(agent){  
    agent@N<-agent@N + 1
    agent
}

#Call the function.  
agentA<-add_one(agentA)
```

I know this works and it's really important to me that the structure is modular and easy to debug, but I'm wondering about the overhead of passing the agent object back and forth.  Most of the objects contain arrays with a few thousand numbers, and they will get passed back and forth thousands of times.  Is there a more efficient way to do it, or is this close enough to best practice?

I'm not really clear on how many times the object gets copied, versus when only a pointer is passed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example you give would result in two full-copy operations and wouldn't be very efficient. This is more or less impossible in S4. The two options are to use a reference class (R6 or refClass), or to do it at the C(++) level with `Rcpp`.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I was afraid of.  I've hesitated to use Reference classes since they are mutable, which makes debugging harder, but maybe I'll have to go that way.  PS I'd accept your comment as the answer if you enter it as such rather than a comment (not sure how to do that myself).